# Javascript Syntax error, unrecognized expression: when using % in id

Tags: javascript

for reasons i can't go into too much details with here i have an id that could look like this:

1%20

The reason i have this is because im matching a table of alot of data.

1 means the table row 20 is the list it is in (from the database).

Now i have the following javascript code:

```
function getSplitId(id) {
    return id.split('%');
}
```

Which works fine when i do the following:

```
selected_row_id = getSplitId($(this).get(0).id)[0];
```

Now i want to get the HTML id of the row ive clicked and for that i have the following code:

```
rowHtmlId = $(this).id;
```

Which also works fine however when i need to start using the rowHtmlId to something like for instance:

```
newElement = $('#' + rowHtmlId).prev();
```

I get the following error:

```
Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #44%24
```

So my question is how can i go around this?

Comment: Use `this.id` instead of `$(this).id` (jQuery object vs DOM element)

Comment: I'm nearly certain you can use a better/valid id naming convention.

Comment: `rowHtmlId = $(this).id;` shouldn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a look at the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/), you see

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as  `!"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[\]^`{|}~` ) as a literal part of a name, it must be escaped with with two backslashes: `\\`.

`%` is a meta character so you have to escape it first:

```
newElement = $('#' + rowHtmlId.replace('%', '\\%')).prev();
```

Or you simply use `getElementById`:

```
$(document.getElementById(rowHtmlId)).prev();
```

Or **even better** (depending on the context), just keep a reference to the row element itself:

```
var row = $(this);
// ... later
newElement = row.prev();
```

There is no need to query for it again if you already have a reference to it.

Answer (score -2):

Just add a backslash to escape the percent sign:

```
id.split('\%');
```

in getSplitId() change from:

```
return id.split('%');
```

to

```
return id.split('\%');
```

Comment: Even though im happy for the response i don't see how this helps me? i dont wish to split the id just select and use it later?

Comment: Please edit the title of your post :) I answered the question in your title :) Sounds like you have many questions. Good Luck :)

Comment: This does not even solve the problem mentioned in the title, because `'%'` with `split` doesn't generate such an error: http://jsfiddle.net/nGYy7/. FYI, in JavaScript, the strings `'\%'` and `'%'` are 100% identical. Compare `console.log('\%')` vs `console.log('%')`.